# Connecting directly to an Oracle Database using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, oracle-dbms

I have an Oracle database that I would like to do `INSERTS` and `UPDATES` on.

I would like to do this using `python` inside a standard `QGIS` installation without having to install additional packages or clients.

Is this possible and in that case, how can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the *DB Manager* plugin in `QGIS` I found that it is possible to use the `QT` framework to connect to an Oracle database and perform `SELECTS`, `UPDATES` and `INSERTS`.

The following shows a quick and dirty example of how it can be done:

```
from qgis.PyQt.QtSql import QSqlDatabase, QSqlQuery

# Check if the driver is available.
if not QSqlDatabase.isDriverAvailable('QOCI'):
    print 'Oracle driver not available'

db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QOCI")

# Do NOT set the host name directly. 
#You'll get a ORA-12505: TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor.
#db.setHostName(HOST)

db.setDatabaseName(HOST + '/' + DATABASE)

# You should probably not the port number either.
#db.setPort(1521)
# Instead insert the port number like:
db.setDatabaseName(HOST + ':' + str(PORT) + '/' + DATABASE)

db.setUserName(USER)
db.setPassword(PASSWORD)

if not db.open():
    print 'Could not open connection.'

q = QSqlQuery(db)
q.exec_('SELECT count(*) FROM my_table')
while(q.first()):
    print(str(q.value(0)))

db.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is via "Ocispatial":

```
from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from qgis.PyQt.QtSql import QSqlDatabase, QSqlQuery
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTableView, QApplication
import sys



#qgis.utils.iface.messageBar().pushMessage("Autosave", u"blba : "+str(QSqlDatabase.drivers()))


# Check if the driver is available.
if not QSqlDatabase.isDriverAvailable('QOCISPATIAL'):
    qgis.utils.iface.messageBar().pushMessage("Autosave", u"Driver not da")


db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QOCISPATIAL")    

db.setPort(1521);
db.setHostName("ddddddddd");
db.setDatabaseName("BiBaBo");
db.setUserName("ruckucku");
db.setPassword("schalalal");

if not db.open():
    qgis.utils.iface.messageBar().pushMessage("x", u"DB closed")


#if db.open():
# assume you have a table called 'users'
query = db.exec_('SELECT OUTPUT_Z from blablabla where FID_AW_BIS='+str(myFeature["FID"])+' OR FID_AW_VON='+str(myFeature["FID"]))
while query.next(): 
record = query.record()
qgis.utils.iface.messageBar().pushMessage("x1", u"DB1: "+str(record.value(0)))

db.close()
```