# What to do about QSqlDatabase: QOCI driver not loaded

Tags: pyqgis, oracle-dbms, database, connection

QGIS - 3.0.1

I am trying to connect to the Oracle database. I am not an expert in QGIS, pyqgis at all. I took help of following code to connect to Oracle database. [Connecting directly to an Oracle Database using PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/241807/connecting-directly-to-an-oracle-database-using-pyqgis/242027#242027)

I used the above code using my hostname, port, database name, username and password.

I get following message when I run the code through OsGeo4W shell.

```
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.0\bin>python-qgis.bat "C:\Arundhati\Automation Test Scri
pt\Radio Signal\QGIS_Test_Run3.py"
Oracle driver not available
QSqlDatabase: QOCI driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QOCISPATIAL QOCISPATIAL8 QSPATIALITE QSQLITE QM
YSQL QMYSQL3 QODBC QODBC3 QPSQL QPSQL7
Could not open connection.
QSqlQuery::exec: database not open
```

How to install the QOCI driver? I couldn't find any help online.

Comment: If you search on "Oracle database not open" you should find plenty of links to steps to repair an offline Oracle database.  This is not client-specific, as it is a server problem.

Comment: Are you sure about this? My guess was it could not open the connection because driver is not available?

Comment: Yes. It's been the better part of a decade since I last used Oracle, but "database not open" had been an indication of failure to start successfully for the two decades before that,

Comment: But the database is not offline. I am using it right now.

Comment: The error message "database not open" is an Oracle error indicating the server is offline (technically started, but in an intermediate state). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27280405/how-do-i-resolve-this-ora-01109-database-not-open-error

Comment: I was on the same link when you posted above message. But the database is active currently. I can query it. If it was in intermediate state, I shouldn't be able to access or query it?

Comment: It could be a driver error, but then the driver developer was on the malicious side to hijack a well-known error message to engender such confusion.

Comment: Is there any alternate solution to this? As far as possible I do not want to install third party libraries. I want to use what is built in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used to same code but I used the QOCISPATIAL driver while making database connection which worked perfectly. I hope it is useful for someone.